# Docker does not run cron job files with external origin (host - windows)

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile, supervisord

I use supervisor to run cron and nginx, the problem is when i try to `COPY` or `VOLUME` mount my cron files, it does not run my cron files in /etc/cron.d

But when I `exec -it <container_id> bash` into the container and create the exact same cron file from inside, it is immediately recognized and runs as it should.

Dockerfile :

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:latest

ENV TERM xterm
ENV HOME /root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nginx \
    supervisor \
    curl \
    nano \
    net-tools

RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/*
COPY nginx_conf /etc/nginx

COPY supervisor_conf /etc/supervisor/
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor

COPY crontabs /etc/cron.d/
RUN chmod -R 644 /etc/cron.d/

CMD /usr/bin/supervisord
```

The cron itself

```
* * * * * root curl --silent http://127.0.0.1/cronjob/cron_test_docker.php >> /var/www/html/log/docker_test.log 2>&1
```

cron and nginx run through supervisor

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon = true

[program:nginx]
command = /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
autostart = true

[program:cron]
command = /usr/sbin/cron -f
autostart = true
```

The logs inside `/var/log/supervisor/` relating to cron for `stdout` and `stderr` are empty.

I also tried stripping out supervisor and running cron on its own through phusion and `CMD cron -f` but got the same issue of it not working when the source is external(`COPY` or `VOLUME`) and magically works when created inside the container.

Initially believed it to be a permissions issue and tried `chmod 644` (as this was the permission a file created in the container had) on all files that were the result of `COPY` into.

```
RUN chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/
```

After which tried every possible combination of permissions with `rwx` to no avail.

Also, tried to append the line of the cronjob into `/etc/crontab` but it is not recognized in `crontab -l`.

```
COPY crontab /tmp/crontab
RUN cat crontab >> /etc/crontab
```

It would be really handy if it worked just when it was created through `COPY` or `VOLUME` as it is a hassle to create it manually in the container everytime.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit 1 :**

Some additional information about the file permissions after `COPY` or `VOLUME`.

- When I perform

  ```
  COPY crontabs /etc/cron.d/
  RUN chmod -R 644 /etc/cron.d/
  ```

  Inside the container running `ls -l` inside `/etc/cron.d/` shows

  ```
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118 Jul 20 11:03 wwwcron-cron-docker_test
  ```
- When I mount the folder through my `docker-compose` through `VOLUME`

  ```
  volumes:
      - ./server/crontabs:/etc/cron.d
  ```

  `ls -l` shows

  ```
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 118 Jul 20 11:03 wwwcron-cron-docker_test
  ```
- In addition if I manually create the cron file in the container  it looks like this and this works

  ```
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118 Jul 22 15:50 wwwcron-cron-docker_test_inside_docker
  ```

Clearly there are very different permissions and ownership when making `COPY` or `VOLUME`. But making a `COPY` with exact permissions does not work but seems to work when created in the container.

Comment: What does the crontab file look like inside the container when you import it as a volume?

Comment: @BMitch : Added more information in Edit 1. If what you were asking was the content -  it is the exact same of course.

Comment: What's your host OS? Did you edit the cron file on Windows? Wondering if you have a linefeed issue.

Comment: @BMitch : The host OS is Windows - and yes the cronfile was created in windows. Positive that all cron files have a new line at the end of them. Not near the PC at the moment but do you think a `dos2unix` on all files should do the trick?

Comment: I would try that, the filesize on my test was one byte smaller than your listing.

Comment: @BMitch That was the issue, it now works with unix line endings now. Will create an answer out of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @BMitch was able to find the issue which was related to line endings since my host machine was windows and the cron file origin was windows as well there was a disparity in the line endings thereby cron did not pick it up automatically.

I added this line to my `Dockerfile` and it works like a charm

```
RUN find /etc/cron.d/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

And iterating on that the size of the file is indeed 1 byte smaller when a dos2unix is run, so you can verify if this operation indeed occurred.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117 Jul 25 08:33 wwwcron-cron-docker_test
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the crontab as a separate command in the Dockerfile?

i.e.

```
...
COPY crontabs /path/to/crontab.txt
RUN crontab -u myUser /path/to/crontab.txt
...
```